# Intel Wireless Network Adapter won't allow mac spoofing on Windows but is possible in Linux, how?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mac-address

I have a *Dell Inspiron 15 5558* laptop which consists of **Intel Dual Band Wireless AC** as the WLAN card and the corresponding WLAN driver is installed. I was trying to spoof my address using Windows 10. I tried it using **Technitium MAC Address Changer**, **NoVirus Thanks MAC Address Changer**, **SMAC MAC Address Changer** and even edited the **registry**. Nothing worked. So i searched for other possible ways but in the end I found this:
[Intel's official statement that mac address cannot be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mALiv.png)

So this tells me that the mac address cannot be changed. But on Ubuntu just clicking on *Edit Connections* > *Network Name* > *Entering the required MAC address*, lets me spoof my MAC address.

Therefore, my question is, what does Ubuntu do differently for MAC spoofing and can i do the similar process on Windows to spoof MAC for any network card?

Answer (score 0):

As I know it depend not only on hardware but on driver also.

No wonder different drivers give different capabiliies.

> Beginning with 12.x driver package, the possibility of "spoofing" the MAC address was blocked ...

Try Intel driver package older that 12.0. Like 11.x